# Macro in Excel to add the date in ISO-8601 format

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, microsoft-excel-2013

For some reason, Excel forces me to use my region for footers when I insert the date.  However, it also doesn't auto update when the worksheet opens.  Without the formatting this is a rather trivial issue, however formatting the text is problematic and am not sure how to fix this with all the quotes seemingly needed to be mandatory.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'you need to get the font to size 6, use calibri, use a light grey #DBDBDB perhaps and use ISO-8601
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightFooter = "&""Calibri""&6" & DBDBDB & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd")
End Sub
```

Also now there seems to be a number in the background of the worksheet.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some trying and failing brougt me to this `sub`, of which you can just paste the relevant bits into your own. As you can see I have used `Chr(34)` instead of double quotes to construct the string, because I think that increases readability, that is a personal preference though. Further, you'll notice that I stored the `string` in a variable, which is not strictly necessary, but which helps when you e.g. want to use it in a debugging-message, as I do in my `sub`. I find that in cases such as this it helps to be able to see what the `string`looks like, as it can be kinda hard to keep track of all the quotes, as you already noted.

I am not entirely sure where you went wrong in your own construction of the string, though it seems you lack some quotes around the area where you define the font color, as well as the `&K` which need to precede its hexadecimal value.

For reference, I used [this MSDN-page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822794.aspx) to help with finding the proper formatting codes for headers and footers.

```
Private Sub test()
  'you need to get the font to size 6, use calibri, use a light grey #DBDBDB perhaps and use ISO-8601
  Dim s As String
  s = "&" & Chr(34) & "Calibri" & Chr(34) & " &6 &KDBDBDB " & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd")
  ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightFooter = s
  Debug.Print s
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah I found that article I tried following the example but the fact I needed to quote the Font name I think screwed me up.  Though I enabled all macro security, and it works when I press Play from within the IDE, I temporary changed the date of the computer, opened the workbook and the date did not change automatically unless I pressed play.  Is this normal behaviour, did I put it into the wrong function?

Comment: You need to move the code into some event which fires on you opening the workbook, the worksheet being activated or something else like that, like what you had in your original code (instead of it being in a normal  sub). It shouldn't be too tricky, I think :)

Comment: I thought putting it into `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` would take care of that. But I will Google around.  Thanks!

Comment: It should take care of that, yes. I assume you have put that module into the `ThisWorkbook`-object?

Comment: Yes, that is what I did.